# Avoid allowing users to propose another edit within X minutes when previous edit proposed from same user and for same post has been rejected

Tags: feature-request, proposed-edits

In the past days, an anonymous user proposed an edit for a post that added extra text not originally included, and that essentially changed the meaning of the post.
As the user didn't see any change in the post, he kept suggesting the same edit four times.

I think that when an edit has been rejected, the successive tries to suggest the same edit should be blocked. I understand that catching similar edits is probably impossible, or it would not catch all the possible similar edits.

Probably, it's easier to simply reject any successive suggested edits for a post, when they are proposed X minutes after an edit has been rejected. In this way, who suggested the edit would probably be more careful on the proposed edits, and would avoid edits for single parts of the post, instead of proposing a single edit that changes different parts of the same post.

I know there is already a block for who has too much edits rejected, but it lasts a week, and it is for rejected edits on all the posts. What I propose is trying to avoid the same user suggests more than one edit for the same post, when the first one was rejected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about a per-post, per-user lockout period for rejected edits? I would vote for that. I mean, if I had a vote and all ... [gazes at shoes].